# Create JSON object from string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, javascriptserializer

I am trying to create a JSON string which contains one container and one array. 
I can do this by using a stringbuilder but I am trying to find a better way to get the JSON string; I want:

```
{ "message":{ "text":"test sms"},"endpoints":["+9101234"]}
```

I tried  this:

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
              {
                  text = "test sms",
                  endpoints = "[dsdsd]"
              });
```

And the output is:

```
{"text":"test sms","endpoints":"[dsdsd]"}
```

Any help or suggestions how to get the required format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the most recent version of .NET we have the `System.Text.Json` namespace, making third party libraries unecessary to deal with json.

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

And use the `JsonSerializer` class to serialize:

```
var data = GetData();
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

and deserialize:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

...
var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>("{\"Name\": \"John\"}");
```

Other versions of .NET platform there are different ways like the `JavaScriptSerializer` where the simplest way to do this is using anonymous types, for sample:

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    message = new { text = "test sms" },
                    endpoints = new [] {"dsdsd", "abc", "123"}
                });
```

**Alternatively**, you can define a class to hold these values and serialize an object of this class into a json string. For sample, define the classes:

```
public class SmsDto
{
   public MessageDto message { get; set; }

   public List<string> endpoints { get; set; }
}

public class MessageDto
{
   public string text { get; set; }
}
```

And use it:

```
var sms = new SmsDto()
{
   message = new MessageDto() { text = "test sms" } ,
   endpoints = new List<string>() { "dsdsd", "abc", "123" }
}

string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(sms);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `message` be followed by ` = ` insted of `:` ?

Comment: Yes, you are rigt @MarkBenovsky, thanks. (javascript confusing) haha.